# Where can I find a legend for the vote and answer count color combinations in the question list?

Tags: discussion

In the question list, there are orange circles, green circles, grey circles, etc...  Is there a legend or a key for this somewhere?

Comment: Maybe we could make it a feature request for the FAQ , this was a similar question, http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3390/47291 , And I can't find it in the FAQ which leads me to think that it should be put in there.

Comment: I agree, should be in the FAQ

Answer (score 6):

I think they tried to make them self evident, but...

Orange = no answers
Grey = answer(s) but no accepted answer
Green = has accepted answer